# how to invalidate previous statement

Tags: conjunctions

How could I properly write this statement in a formal way:

> Whenever I ask him to stop, he does, but continues again 5 minutes later.

I am not sure if "but continues again 5 minutes later" is correct.

I am wondering if I could replace it for:

", then continues it again 5 minutes later"
", then continues again 5 minutes later"

Perhaps should I rewrite the whole sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: **Continue again** sounds strange because [continue] [1] already carries the meaning "start again after a pause". Either **continue** or **resume** on their own, or **start again** would be better. **start again** is less formal. [1]: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/continue?q=Continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is correct and understandable, you could add

> Whenever I ask him to stop, he does, but ***then he*** continues again 5 minutes later.
>
> Whenever I ask him to stop, he does, but ***then he*** continues ***doing it*** again 5 minutes later.

All variations would be understood to be equivalent.

Comment: Could you say which one sounds more formal? I would like to not repeat the pronoun `he`, so I should use the sentence quoted in the question, right?